# Predict bounding box only

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am having two folders training and testing. Each folder has 14k images of a random **single** object like chair , box ,fan , can ,etc..
Addition to this i have 4 columns [x1,x2,y1,y2] for each image of training set in which that random object is enclosed(bounding box).
With this information i want to predict the bounding boxes for the test set.
I am very new in Computer Vision,It would be very helpful if any one can help me how to start with training such kind of models.
I found yolov3 but it includes classification as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you see the github code [here](https://github.com/roy881020/pytorch-yolo2).

In detect.py, there is [do_detect()](https://github.com/roy881020/pytorch-yolo2/blob/6b2538b0ec314486479173920e6cacafbf5cd9e6/detect.py#L31) function.

this function returns both class and bbox that you want to get from image.

```
boxes = do_detect(model, image, confidence_threshold, nms_threshold)
```